# Unable to get variable from another job in github actions workflow using outputs

Tags: linux, github, variables, github-actions, variable-assignment

Note: if I change `echo "formatdate=$date" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT` to `echo "::set-output name=formatdate::$date"` then it works !!. But I do not wish to go by this solution as `set-output` is deprecated.

I wish to get the `date` variable of job `SETVARS` to be printed in another job `TAKING _BACKUP` using Linux self-hosted runners.

I am unable to assign the value of `date` to another variable within the job `SETVARS` and hence I m unable to read it in the different job `TAKING_BACKUP`.

I have been able to get this to work on Windows Runner and I m unaware of how to get it to work on Linux Runner.

```
---

name: Refresh_poc - AD
env:
  DBenv: 'STG'

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:

  SETVARS:

    outputs:
      formatdate: "${{ steps.get-date.outputs.formatdate }}"

    runs-on: 'self-hosted-unixhost1'

    steps:

      - name: Get present date
        id: get-date
        run: |
          date=$(date +"%d%b%Y")
          echo "Date is: $date"
          echo "formatdate=$date" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          echo "Date output iss: ${{ steps.get-date.outputs.formatdate }}"
          echo "formatdate=$date" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "Data env iss: ${{ env.formatdate }}"

  TAKING_BACKUP:

    needs:
      - SETVARS

    runs-on: ' self-hosted-unixhost1'

    steps:   

      - name: Taking backup

        run: |
           echo "CO_date_is ${{ needs.SETVARS.outputs.formatdate }}"
```

Output:

> Run date=$(date +"%d%b%Y")
>
> Date is: 18Jul2023
>
> Date output iss:
>
> Data env iss:

Kindly assist.

Update: Tried the below suggestion as suggested in the comments under `job` SETVARS3`and`TAKING_BACKUP3` but it too
does not help. See Snapshot:

https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#eJytUV1rwjAUfe+vOHQVNkYKey04qHM4ETbRdjCGSNpG26lJaRIYOP/7krTq2MfbnpLcc+6955xwumMRZmzVMFkua5GDIB56gkceUGtZ2hPIGsrzkskIrzta8YX3JjJpofl98hzP5i1LaFVrJdsHsBLNjqqCKrMh2O8hFatluGaK2FrYscMzDYeDa200l8RIgM40V5psDSYVLiDZdkVKYQYVRPPq3V5vXIubfVxMwJ2tEVOojTHGFez8DgaqIsJRx6lotkb4OD3hWvrBpVN27feKXtZ78a++EFheCvhDi1cmmsAy/R/42V+/ZeD2Fn4wGicP6WD5lCbTNPE905bEk/HjaDmI7ybptPXCGSts6F3Mi3+NJ6Gbiq+R0Xyj679j+O7S/KSTFXaifv9I3/sEnnGxKg==

I tried the suggestion here but it does not help.

https://github.com/knowyrtech/variables/actions/runs/5604679033/workflow

[image]

Comment: Looks like your self-hosted runner is Linux with shell/Bash as the default shell but you're using Powershell syntax to set the env var and the output parameter i.e. `$env:GITHUB_OUTPUT`. `env:` is not needed in shell/Bash. Simply use `$GITHUB_ENV` and `$GITHUB_OUTPUT`. Also, env var set in a step are only available in the next steps, not in the same step. See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable, https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter.

Comment: @Azeem I tried your suggestion and updated the original post by removing `env:` however, the problem persist and unable to print. You can use any Ubuntu Linux runner to replicate the issue.

Comment: Please update your question with what you tried.

Comment: Updated @Azeem... U can try both the jobs in any Ubuntu or Linux runner and u will see that the value of `formatdate` is blank (not printed) in job `TAKING_BACKUP`

Comment: Try [this](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#eJytUV1rwjAUfe+vOHQVNkYKey04qHM4ETbRdjCGSNpG26lJaRIYOP/7krTq2MfbnpLcc+6955xwumMRZmzVMFkua5GDIB56gkceUGtZ2hPIGsrzkskIrzta8YX3JjJpofl98hzP5i1LaFVrJdsHsBLNjqqCKrMh2O8hFatluGaK2FrYscMzDYeDa200l8RIgM40V5psDSYVLiDZdkVKYQYVRPPq3V5vXIubfVxMwJ2tEVOojTHGFez8DgaqIsJRx6lotkb4OD3hWvrBpVN27feKXtZ78a++EFheCvhDi1cmmsAy/R/42V+/ZeD2Fn4wGicP6WD5lCbTNPE905bEk/HjaDmI7ybptPXCGSts6F3Mi3+NJ6Gbiq+R0Xyj679j+O7S/KSTFXaifv9I3/sEnnGxKg==).

Comment: @Azeem does not help. Updated the original post and tried your suggestion here: https://github.com/knowyrtech/variables/actions/runs/5604679033/workflow

Comment: Typo in the job name. See https://github.com/knowyrtech/variables/actions/runs/5604679033/workflow#L102. Should be `needs.SETVARS3` and not `needs.SETVARS`. Linting with https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/ should be helpful for these syntax issues.